# Windows 10 unable to delete files

Tags: windows, long-integer, names

This is a bit of a different issue from other questions like this. I've tried all the other solutions and they didn't work for me. It's not that my filenames are too long, though they are the filename is actually a directory path...for example g:\backup\folderwithfilestodelete\"**z:\backup\folderwithfilestodelete\filetodelete.jpg**"
Bold is the name. without the quotes. The actual filenames begin with z:\ windows won't let me delete them nor can I rename them. I've tried the free solutions posted but non work for me.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution that worked.

From this link, last solution suggested. https://serverfault.com/questions/95581/delete-file-containing-invalid-characters-in-windows

Right clicked on the drive, tools, error checking. it found errors, and after telling it to repair, the files are gone, and I'm able to delete the directories.